# How to create a preview of html code on mobile devices?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there anyway that i could to create a button that creates a popup/modal to simulate a visualization of html code on mobile devices?

I have a textarea where the user could put html code and send it via email.

I would like to create a preview of this html code on mobile devices such as iphone. I was trying to use an iframe 960x580 and it looks too big ( and i have a big monitor ) but if i use a lower monitor, the same iframe looks so strange. This will be a feature on my interface so i can't use tools like 'device mode' from Chrome.

Anyone have an idea how can i do it?

Comment: @Jeremy Wilken's answer is a good one, but I just wanted to add that the reason the iframe looks "too big" on your screen is because of the difference in pixel density (PPI). Most desktop screens usually have between 72 and ~100 pixels per inch, but retina iPhones have ~300 pixels per inch.

Comment: You should use HTML entities.

Comment: Please see my comment on @Jeremy Wilken's answer.

Comment: @Elle can i simulate those pixes?

Comment: @Placplacboom, well that's the thing, different devices will have different pixel densities and sizes. It's quite difficult to account for those variations. Even Photoshop, has trouble doing this with it's "Print Size" button. (Print graphics are usually 300 DPI, whilst monitors are traditionally around 72 PPI.) So, from what I can tell Photoshop simply scales the preview to 1/4th of its original resolution which gives a better on-screen approximation of the actual print size of the document. You could try doing something along those lines, but expect artifacts and blurry text.

Comment: Let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: Have you found the answer for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome Canary has a handy feature just for this https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/device-mode

It will let you pick a lot of different devices and while its not a true emulator it is a useful tool for previewing.

Comment: I've saw this tool and another tools like that. This not work for me because i need this control on my interface, it will be like a 'feature' for the user, got it? The user insert his HTML code and he could check how that code will look on mobile.

Comment: @ Placplacboom, in that case you should use javascript or Jquery to open a new window with the appropriate dimensions, please see the link: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp  Note however, that this won't solve the scaling issue caused by any pixel density differential that may exist.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at this site?:

http://responsivetest.net/

Simply put in your websites URL and you can select what type of device you would like to view it on.

Answer (score 0):

Many simulators will do this job,

1. Ripple emulator for chrome.
2. [Responsinator](https://www.responsinator.com/)
3. [Remote debuging](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging)

Above are some good methods to test your webpages